# Firestore full-text search

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating an app from GAE/J Datastore to Cloud Firestore. The app uses GAE Full Text Search service. The Firestore docs [recommend using Algolia/ElasticSearch for full-text search](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search).

Is there anything that prevents using the search service with Firestore? Why is the docs recommending external search services esp. Google being known for search

Thanks

Comment: I think because of index overhead. To do a full-text search you might need to store different indexes of a single text. Which will increase the cost of your app.

Comment: You can take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)** where I have explained step by step, how you can achieve this if want with Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036384/4508504

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that prevents you from using [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) and the [App Engine Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/) together; it's just also possible to use Cloud Firestore outside of App Engine, so we don't want to constrain users to any particular environment.