# Text search on firestore document field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud firestore as my database for my angular application. I wanted to implement text based search but the only option I see is using Angolia but I don’t want to use a 3rd party service. Is it possible to implement text search with just the functionality provided by firestore. Even if it returns the object by matching the first characters will work for me it does not have to be a “contain” query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966687/firestore-full-text-search, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195122/firestore-comparison-operators-contains-does-not-contain-starts-with, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942242/flutter-search-through-text-data-from-firestore/49942559#49942559, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285039/firestore-search-like/48287341#48287341

Comment: Specifically the answer from Sam here seems what you want, as it shows how to find documents where the field starts with a certain value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916173/209103

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not support full text search in any form.  That's why the documentation suggests the use of another service.

Comment: I was able to get the logic implemented using the following code

databaseReference.orderByChild('_searchLastName')
                 .startAt(queryText)
                 .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff")

Comment: That's searching on a string prefix, not full text search.